# How can you skip multiple IDs?

Tags: tfs, skip, except

How can you skip multiple IDs in TFS (Visual Studio Team Foundation Server) and not in SQL?
For example, a query to return all non-closed bugs, except bugs #123, 174, 185, etc.?

Today, I write:

```
Created By = @me
AND State <> Closed
AND ID <> 123
AND ID <> 174
AND ID <> 185
```

I'm looking for a query to group the exceptions, something like:

```
Created By = @me
AND State <> Closed
AND ID NOT IN 123, 174, 185
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in WIQL. You can do 'in' but not 'not in'. This has not changed in 8 years: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx

You could however put the offending bugs into another area or iteration to filter them out.

Comment: No, I cannot, because all that data remains relevant and mustn't be altered, except the history contents, but history also cannot be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older but I didn't see this solution listed. We have a query run by QA and UAT needs a subset of that list. I added a tag to the items we did not want them to track:

```
Non-UAT Item
```

Then copied the query QA used and added a **Does Not Contain** operator to the **Tags** field. Now we can easily update any items that we do not want UAT to be concerned with.